# Sorting Boxes for optimal bin packing

Tags: sorting, volume, surface, bin-packing

I am currently working on a Bin Packing program and need to know what would be the most efficient way of getting boxes (arbitrary width, length, and height) to be sorted in the manner below?

> Biggest (Cube-like) shaped boxes then Tallest (Thin-like) shaped boxes

TO

> Smallest (Cube-like) shaped boxes then shortest (Thin-like) shaped
>   boxes

I have tried sorting Volume Then Height, Height then Volume, and Surface-Area then Height. They are decent ways to do it but I want a more optimal solution.

Comment: What is your criteria for a "good" solution? For example, how would you sort a 2x2x2 cube, a 10x5x5 box, a 4x1x1 box, and a 7x5x5 box? Why?

Comment: I would place in this following order:                                                       10x5x5; (It has the largest volume and is cube-shaped enough to be placed first), 7x5x5 (It has the second largest volume and is cube-shaped enough as well; 2x2x2 (The third largest volume with cube shaped), 4x1x1 (smallest volume that is not cube shaped whatsoever) @templatetypedef